# Laravel relationships in eloquent model

Tags: php, database, laravel

I'm trying to add a "simple" relationship into my Route model, but I must have overlooked something because it's not working.

I want my Route to have many steps and the steps should only have one Route, but my code does not find any steps. What did I miss?

routes table:

```
     Schema::create('routes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('uuid')->unique();
        $table->decimal('start_lat', 11, 8);
        $table->decimal('start_lng', 11, 8);
        $table->decimal('end_lat', 11, 8);
        $table->decimal('end_lng', 11, 8);
        $table->string('start_address');
        $table->string('end_address');
        $table->integer('distance');
        $table->integer('duration');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

steps table:

```
    Schema::create('steps', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('uuid')->unique();
        $table->integer('route_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('route_id')->references('id')->on('routes');
        $table->integer('distance');
        $table->integer('duration');
        $table->decimal('start_lat', 11, 8);
        $table->decimal('start_lng', 11, 8);
        $table->decimal('end_lat', 11, 8);
        $table->decimal('end_lng', 11, 8);
        $table->string('instructions');
        $table->text('polyline');
    });
```

Route model:

```
public function steps() {
    return $this->hasMany(Step::class, 'route_id', 'id');
}
```

Step model:

```
public function route() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Route::class);
}
```

The way I call it in the controller:

```
    $route = Route::all()->where('id', 1)->first();
    $steps[] = $route->steps();
```

Comment: What does `dd(Route::all());` show you? Is there a route with that id? Does it have any steps? "It's not working" does not provide a lot of room to assist.

Comment: Sorry, i misspelled the problem.  It should be: ..but my code does not find any steps. I do find the routes.

Comment: Ok, what does `dd(Step::all());` show you? Are there steps with that route_id?

Comment: When I return the $route->steps(), I get this error: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany could not be converted to string

Comment: Well that's completely different from not finding any steps. Don't try to `echo` or otherwise treat it as a string.

Comment: It shows me the 34 entries there is and some of them I know have a route_id of 1.

Comment: I'm not using echo. I'm returning the object as a json.

Comment: That error message means you're trying to treat it as a string. Show your code.

Comment: public function checkroute(Request $request) {
        $route = Route::all()->where('id', 1)->first();
        return $route->steps();
    }

Comment: That's not returning it as JSON.

Comment: thanks for your help and time. But it's resolved now

Comment: In future, including error messages and your actual code in the question will save a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a collection with steps?

But instead you get eloquent `steps()`

Try and change it for:

```
$steps[] = $route->steps;
```

Comment: thanks. The problem was that it should be $route->steps; and NOT $route->steps();

Comment: Or use toJSON method on the Eloquent relationship: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json